# Can I reuse the title of a previous poster presentation for my PhD thesis?

Tags: phd, thesis, poster

I'm currently writing my Ph.D. dissertation, and I would like to use for my thesis exactly the same title as for one of my previous poster presentations.Is this OK?

Comment: You can, but why do not you want to change it!

Comment: Ask your supervisor.

Comment: It's your dissertation, so *you* decide on the title. Unless you don't want to make decisions, but im getting sarcastic. Just make it convincing, like the rest of your thesis.

Answer (score 8):

I did *exactly* the same thing and am regretting it slightly. No one seemed to care, but for some reason the poster is listed on Google Scholar separately from my thesis but under an identical title. I could have avoided the "disambiguation needed" situation altogether by renaming one of them (preferably by saving the really nifty thesis title for the thesis, and using a work-in-progress version for the poster).

Comment: I guess you're right: If there is a naming conflict, that would most often mean that one of the titles was not fitting.

Comment: @Karl: I don't think that's what TrikeProf wanted to say. The title could very well be fitting both the poster and the thesis, but using the same name twice (however appropriate otherwise) is likely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Use a title that makes sense for your dissertation. A dissertation is way more detailed than a poster so ideally your title would reflect this. Elaborating on the answer above, you might want to use another name, given that there is already a document with the same name.